# iOS 11.3: Device Management Menu Not Available

Tags: ios, ios11, device-management

I'm getting an extremely frustrating error where the device management menu on iOS 11.3 beta appears and disappears randomly. I have a profile set up for my developer apps which is visible under General > Profiles, but it's not allowing me to give permission to my app.

[image: XCode error]

XCode error (after building the app)

[image: iOS error]

iOS error (after attempting to start the app)

[image: General Menu]

General Menu

[image: After clicking Profile]

After clicking Profile

[image: Profile Menu]

Profile Menu

Nowhere in these menus is a Device Management tab like XCode claims. The weird part is this issue is intermittent. Every so often I magically find that the Profiles option has become Profiles & Device Management and I can confirm the app. But not often.

Comment: Your reconnect your device once again, then you can get pop up like trust this computer

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that's slightly different. I'm handling the certificates that come with code signing on XCode. The "trust this computer" is a more general security measure not specific to app development

Comment: When you updated on in iphone

Comment: R u selected developer account in xcode

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I'm signed in with my Apple Developer account and code signing is turned on

Comment: Is your device registered to that account, or not. Every connected device will registered to developer account, at that time one trusted​certificate will generated and that device id will be saved in account.

Comment: And one more is if you're account is free account, it accept up to three or five only.

Comment: I have a paid Apple developer account. My phone is registered to the account

Comment: did you fixed it? Im facing the same problem